# How to find un-Used Workflow Email ALerts?

Tags: apex, soql, tooling-api

My requirement is to find un-Used `workflow email alerts` which are not tied to any `Workflow Rules`

I am checking Tooling API option  [WorkflowAlert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowalert.htm)

Where I am thinking of doing SOQL on `Workflow EMail Alert` like

```
select id,DeveloperName,SenderType,templateId,EntityDefinitionId from WorkflowAlert
```

I thought of something like `WOrkflow` will be parent and in SOQL I will put something like `WorkflowId = null` which will tell me no workflow rule is associated with this Email Alert but I don't think thats an option available looking at the object definition.

Please advise if there is any way to find out `Workflow Email Alert` not assigned to any `Workflow Rule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details you seek are in the ToolingAPI, but are a little difficult to access.

What you want is the [`WorkflowRule.Metadata`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowrule.htm). This contains the `actions`, which is a  `WorkflowActionReference` collection. Essentially, these relate the `WorkflowRule` to the `WorkflowAlert`.

Of course, the problem with doing this via the Tooling API is that you can only query the `Metadata` field for a single record at a time. So you would need to get each WorkflowRule and slowly build up a complete collection of all the referenced workflow alerts. And then you can compare that to the actual list to find which ones aren't used.

---

Here is a view of that data from a debugging session against a `WorkflowRule.Metadata`.

[image].

**DFB__Notify_Customer** corresponds to the WorkflowAlert `NamespacePrefix` and `DeveloperName` fields in my dev org.

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel Ballinger

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a single email alert, You can do that by going to email alert detail in setup.

[image]

It has a related list to show to the workflow rules using this alert.if there is no workflow using this, it says **This alert is currently not used by any rules**.

Comment: No, of course I am not looking for single email alert.

Answer (score 0):

Email alerts can be `queried` from the `developer console` by checking `Use Tooling API`. But I am afraid you can not find Unused workflow email alerts with SOQL.

Email Alerts are `configuration`, not data.  `SOQL won't be able to help you`.
I don't know of a shortcut other than looking through all the Alerts one by one.